# Safest way to access a service without directly using a VPN

Tags: network, vpn, ssh

I'm not sure if this site is the best option to be asking it, but could not find a better fit.

Imagine I have some services (SSH and RDP, mainly) exposed on my personal desktop, running at my home.

When I'm traveling, I usually login to a VPN my router is running and consume those services. Thus, my router does not expose any port that links directly to my computer.

Now, however, I'm using a company-issued laptop when traveling and guidelines specify that I should not install any VPN software, which prevents me from using my previous approach.

I've thought about two work-arounds, but would like some confirmation/alternatives.

#### Option 1: Exposing the services directly to the internet

This would consist of creating virtual servers on my router, linking directly to the services on my desktop. I don't feel comfortable with this approach because a) RDP doesn't seem to be built to be publicly accessible and b) even if I was exposing only SSH, I'm not confident I would be able to set it up 100% and/or detect if someone breached in

#### Option 2: Having other device connect to the VPN and expose the services to the LAN

This would consist of having a somewhat portable device (like a Raspberry Pi) connected to the same network I'm using; this device would connect to my home VPN and act somewhat as a jump-server. I connect to the Pi on some port and it "redirects" me to my desktop (through the VPN).

Don't know exactly how to pull this off, but it seems very safe (as it is not exposing anything to the internet).

Comment: Can you create VMs on you company laptop, in which you could connect to the VPN? That said, would your company find it acceptable that you are connecting to/using personal services of yours?

Comment: See https://github.com/anderspitman/awesome-tunneling. Basic approach for most: have a service running on the public internet, have the inner service connect through some connector to the public service. Inner server and client access meet at the public service where authentication is done and if successful both sides are spliced together to create the authenticated tunnel.

Comment: Some routers (especially if flashed to tun [OpenWRT](https://openwrt.org/) or something like it) can run their own SSH servers, so you'd be able to run `ssh -D1080 myrouter` and drop in a dynamic SOCKS proxy to use from your web browser and other software.